# Is it better to have just two good letters of recommendation, or two good letters and one bad letter, if three are expected?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

Some universities say that "The minimum number of letters of recommendation are 2 but we highly encourage 3". If I know that I can get 2 good letters of recommendation but they "highly encourage 3", should I send in a third?

Comment: "Bad" or just not stellar? A letter that says you are a terrible person, have no work ethic, and are as dumb as a post, i.e. one that actively disparages you, could certainly kill your application. A mediocre letter is a somewhat different story.

Comment: I was thinking more of "not stellar". Just a so-so letter.

Comment: Two and a half is more than two.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes That's almost certainly not the right way of looking at this.

Comment: A mediocre third letter is generally worse than no third letter, (when a third letter is not required).

Comment: @xLeitix Quite so--there's almost certainly no such thing as half a letter.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it better to have 2 good letters or recommendation or 2 good and 1 bad letter?

Definitely, it's better to have two good letters.  A bad letter is a very, very bad thing.

They're not counting -- they're reading for understanding.

Comment: "They" will also wonder why there weren't 3 letters, since other applicants have 3... "Cherry-picking" faculty contacts suggests itself, etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett "The minimum number of letters of recommendation are 2."

Comment: @paulgarrett Isn't selecting your letter writers by definition "cherry-picking"?

Comment: @xLeitix, sure, selecting 3 is ... selecting... but only being able to come up with 2, instead of 3, is an indicator that one's fan base is 33% smaller, etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett On reading the quoted instructions, someone might think, "I have 2 strong letters and one positive but not so strong letter, I'll stop at 2."  Or "I have 2 good letters, and my third reference is in a dig in Asia at the moment, so I'll stop at 2."  Or "I am a returning student and I could only find 2 references after my childrearing gap."  If they require 3 letters they should ask for 3 letters.

Comment: @aparente001, "strongly suggested/encouraged" is a pretty strong hint. Not making it a "rule" simply gives flexibility for the decision-makers, but should not be viewed as being "unclear" about what is wanted.

Comment: @paulgarrett - How about putting your point of view in an Answer?  (I am not really sure exactly what your point of view is....)

Answer (score 6):

If you can't feel assured that that third letter writer will write a positive letter, forget it.  Don't risk having a negative or even so-so letter in your file.

Answer (score 2):

They may count, or not, depending. My department would count because every application had to qualify for submission for graduate fellowships (policy decision), where 3 means 3. (There was also a quota of "exceptions", they could spend an exception if the candidate was worth it). Not all departments will care. Not all faculty and disciplines have fallen victim to praise-inflation, so a simple letter stating that you did a competent job in your work could be good enough, especially if the writer is known for being conservative in praise.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different dimensions of the value of a recommendation letter that are relevant here:

1. The quality ascribed by the writer to the recommendee.
2. The certainty or itensity of that statement.
3. The reputation of the letter writer himself/herself.

A letter that scores high in the first category, but is less persuasive on the other ones, should not be detrimental. A typical example would be "CANDIDATE attend my course on X, participated well and scored top grades in the exam." This won't get you far, but also shouldn't hold you back.

A letter that is not good *because of* the first criterion is problematic. A letter which scores very low on the first and very high on the third will probably kill of an application regardless of most other circumenstances.

Answer (score 1):

If only to clarify my comments to other answers: if the "instructions" say "minimum 2 letters, 3 strongly suggested", or similar, it means that the admissions committee reserves the right to consider situations with only 2 letters... but certainly *not* that it hardly matters. It matters. A solid 3rd letter is fine, and infinitely better than no third letter, for at least two reasons. One is the mere "strongly encouraged" message, which, if effectively disregarded, amounts to a "failed diagnostic". The other is the subtler issue about appraisal of a student's potential: as it happens, it seems possible to get one super-enthusiastic letter, and one more "pretty good", ... but it's hardly to bluff to a third that is "ok". Further, and perhaps surprisingly to students, the "second excellent letter" is very often not-so-sterling-after-all, and this unexpected loss can be compensated by hearing from a third, "disinterested but informed" party, that the student has good chops. So... everyone, including the student, wants that third letter.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your position.  "A solid 3rd letter is fine, and infinitely better than no third letter" is a good point in response to a different question!